# will anybody see my new answer to an old question?

Tags: support, answers, old-questions

Few minutes ago I Needed to do something, googled and found the exact question on SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666511/installing-bcrypt-ruby-gem-on-windows), but with an unperfect answer; googling more, I found the solution, and went back to insert my own answer (so I'll find it the next time I need it).

Other than the asker, and of course people trying to solve that same problem (and me next time, when I'll have forgotten it), will anybody ever know that answer exists?

Or, from the opposite point of view: how can I know that somebody just answered an old question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, adding an answer to an existing question will bump that question to the homepage and bring it back to life again (until of course, it eventually floats down again as every question does in a typical SO question life cycle).

You are encouraged to add a new answer to an old question to improve the information contained there, if you are lucky, the OP can even switch the accepted answer (I've done it on some of my questions that are more than 8 months old when something better came along)