# Old question, new answer ... but it doesn't float to the top?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, old-questions, homepage, new-answers

According to *[will anybody see my new answer to an old question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41851)* a new answer will cause an old question to bubble up to the frontpage. However, I have recently answered a few old questions and unfortunately it seems they don't follow the same rule anymore. Examples:

1. [make yields “commands commence before first target” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588551/)
2. [LNK2019 unresolved external symbol NtOpenFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774967/)

I tried different browsers and also without logging in, just to make sure I wouldn't be subjected to some filtering based on tags or some such.

My question: has this behavior been changed (and if so when)?

Comment: It will show up in the "active" tab. And it *may* (randomly) show up on the front page.

Comment: It must've been flooding with questions at the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Overflow's front page is special. Because Stack Overflow receives a ton of questions every day, the front page there shows "interesting" questions instead of just the recently active ones that other sites see.

When you answer or edit an older question on Stack Overflow, it's bumped up to the top of every view that's sorted by activity - https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c?sort=active&pagesize=50 (for the [c](/questions/tagged/c) tag, for example), etc.

Comment: Aaah, thanks. That explains it of course. Very enlightening. I'll upvote now and accept after I get some sleep (unless of course someone comes up with an even more brilliant answer :))